# Django bug with a tag

Tags: django, tags

My code

```
{% if GET['search'] % }
            {% block count codes|length as counter %}
```

**Is the following a valid if -clause as a Django tag?**

```
{% if GET['search'] % }
```

The following code gives me an error that *block* takes only one argument.
**What is wrong in the code?**

```
{% block count codes|length as counter %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django isn't PHP.

You're trying to use a template filter inside a template tag. You can use either a tag or a filter, but not both.

For that matter, since the `block` tag takes only a label for the block, I'm not sure what the template code you've written is supposed to do. Additionally, are you sure that `GET['search']` is valid syntax in a template tag?

I'm guessing a little at your view and template requirements, but here's how I would approach this in your place. There are a number of gaps you'll have to fill in for yourself depending on your circumstances.

In `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    request_was_search = False
    codes = []

    if request.GET.has_key('search'):
        request_was_search = True
        codes = some_function_you_define_to_get_codes()

    return render_to_response('foo.html',
                              {'codes':codes,
                               'request_was_search':request_was_search})
```

In the template:

```
{% block count %}
    {% if request_was_search %}
        // do whatever you want here
        <p>There were {{ codes|length }} codes submitted.</p>
        // end example
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It's not true to say you can't use filter syntax within a tag. That completely depends on how the tag is written - you can definitely evaluate filters within the tag, if the tag calls the relevant resolving functions.

Answer (score 3):

That's incorrect syntax. Try this:

```
{% if GET.search % }
```

This assumes you have GET in the context passed to your template.

Comment: +1 rule of thumb, you never use dictionary syntax in a template.

Comment: @Chase: Unfortunately, I am unconvinced of the existence of these people called "template designers." That means that the template is either being done by a designer ... nah, ain't gonna happen, or a programmer ... yeah, that's what happens in my neighborhood. I think they really need to look at reality here and go with Jinja2 or something very close to it (it's faster, too).

Answer (score 1):

First define blocks, then add code inside

```
{% block header %}
 <h1>My Site</h1>
{% endblock header %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first line of your code:
{% if GET['search'] % }
The extra space between the last two characters % and } is the problem. Remove the space so that %} are close together. The error ('block' tag takes only one argument) would go away.